# Why is acetate a monodentate ligand?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds

Why is the acetate ion considered a monodentate ligand as opposed to a bidentate ligand considering both oxygen atoms can donate their respective lone pair of electrons?

Comment: There is a delocalization of the negative charge over the two Oxygen atoms of the carboxylate group $\ce{-COO^-}$. These Oxygen atoms are not independent from one another. They behave together as a mono dentate ligand.

Comment: Acetate ion is considered a monodentate ligand because it **is** a monodentate ligand (except when it isn't). Then come the explanations.

Answer (score 10):

This depends a lot on the compound in question.

In general, a bidentate acetate would lead to a four-membered ring with the central metal; since the $\ce{O-C-O}$ angle is relatively fixed at approximately $120^\circ$ and since we expect the resulting compound to be at least somewhat symmetric, it would typically lead to unusually small bond angles or a $\ce{C\bond{...}M}$ distance that is too short. If, for example, we imagine $\angle(\ce{O-M-O})=90^\circ$, that means each $\ce{M-O-C}$ angle would be $75^\circ$ which is not what we usually observe in such compounds without a significant force holding it together. Coordinate bonds are usually not very strong, do not liberate enough energy and it would thus be more favourable for one of the two $\ce{O-M}$ bonds to be broken leading to acetate as a monodentate ligand.

There are, however, exceptions. My favourite is probably [$\ce{[Cr2(OAc)4(H2O)2]}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium(II)_acetate) or chromium(II) acetate monohydrate. In this compound, four acetate ions arrange around two chromium atoms in a bidentate fashion; however, each individual acetate bonds to two different chromium ions *via* its two oxygens. In addition, a water molecule sits on each end of the $\ce{Cr-Cr}$ axis and it turns out the bond between the two chromium ions is, in fact, a quadruple bond. The quadruple bond permits the chromium atoms to come close enough to each other so that the acetates can arrange in a preferable configuration.

[image: chromium(II) acetate monohydrate]
(Image taken from [Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Chromium(II)-acetate-dimer-3D-balls.png), where a full list of authors is available)

Comment: My favorite is uranium. With it, acetate works as a bidentate ligand to _one atom_.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Ah, but then it can’t compete with a quadruple bond, can it? ;)

Comment: Yeah, that's a rare gem indeed.

Comment: Searching for acetate metal coordination turned up a few compounds with similar coordination to your chromium(II) acetate: Palladium(II) acetate, Rhodium(II) acetate, Copper(II) acetate, Iron(III) acetate ... it does not seem exceptional at all, except I assumed these are solids and that generally speaking the acetate bonds to *two* metal atoms. So it seemed contrary to the spirit of "bidentate" in the original question. Ivan's uranyl acetate seems closer to the real thing.

Comment: Not the same thing, but fun to see, are basic acetates of [zinc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zinc_acetate) and [beryllium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_beryllium_acetate).  Six acetate ligands bond to all the edges of a metal tetrahedron with a four-coordinate oxygen in the center.

Comment: @BuckThorn You’re raising a good point, namely whether *denticity* refers to bonds made to *a single atom* or bonds made to *any dative bond acceptor*. I understood it to be the latter, but the definitions I can find in two seconds of Googling are not clear enough to exclude either meaning. That said, I prefer chromium(II) over the other metals because it features a 3d metal in a quadruple bond which never ceases to fascinate me.